# VBA - Resize a user input range

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a simply procedure to search range_1 for values that are also in range_2 and highlight them.  This works fine if a user selects just the values in each range.  However, if the user selects an entire column, it will run through all 1+ MM cells (skipping blanks along the way).

Normally you get the last row from a range by using row.end, but how would I do this with a user input range? I could create a new worksheet, paste the ranges and reset them, but I'm wondering if there is better solution out there.

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted your code, that often tells us more than your description of what you're trying to do. For now, all I can tell you is that `Range.Resize()` might help you..

Comment: Try intersecting the selected range with the sheet's `UsedRange`